# FSMC gived hard fault handler on STM32F4

Tags: c, stm32, stm32f4discovery, stm32f4

I am currently working on a project where I try to send data from a FPGA to an ARM-processor(STM32F407). I am trying to do this by using FSMC, where I simulate the FPGA as a nor flash memory seen from the processor. I need to use FSMC because the FPGA samples a lot of data from sensors and from two GPS.

When i use the function `HAL_NOR_Read()` the code crashes into `HardFault_Handler`

FSMC is configured for 8-bit muxed nor-flash memmory.[FSMC config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8W2qW.png)

I am using TrueStudio to program STM32F4 and have used the debugger to go through the assembly code before the code crashes. But I don't think I have knowledge to find the fault there.

Maybe someone else have more knowledge who could help me solve the problem.

Below is the code I use.

```
#include "main.h"
#include "stm32f4xx_hal.h"

SD_HandleTypeDef hsd;

UART_HandleTypeDef huart4;
UART_HandleTypeDef huart1;
UART_HandleTypeDef huart3;

NOR_HandleTypeDef hnor1;
FMC_NORSRAM_TimingTypeDef Timing;

#define NOR_BANK_ADDR ((uint32_t *)0x64000000)
#define BUFFER_SIZE ((uint32_t)16)
uint16_t aRxBuffer[BUFFER_SIZE] = {0};

void SystemClock_Config(void);
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void);
static void MX_FSMC_Init(void);
static void MX_SDIO_SD_Init(void);
static void MX_UART4_Init(void);
static void MX_USART1_UART_Init(void);
static void MX_USART3_UART_Init(void);


int main(void)
{
  HAL_Init();
  SystemClock_Config();

  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_FSMC_Init();
  MX_SDIO_SD_Init();
  MX_UART4_Init();
  MX_USART1_UART_Init();
  MX_USART3_UART_Init();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */
  HAL_NOR_Init(&hnor1,&Timing,&Timing);

  HAL_NOR_Read(&hnor1,NOR_BANK_ADDR,aRxBuffer);


  while (1)
  {    
  }  
}
```

This is the parameters for FSMC

```
static void MX_FSMC_Init(void)
{
  FSMC_NORSRAM_TimingTypeDef Timing;

  /** Perform the NOR1 memory initialization sequence
  */
  hnor1.Instance = FSMC_NORSRAM_DEVICE;
  hnor1.Extended = FSMC_NORSRAM_EXTENDED_DEVICE;
  /* hnor1.Init */
  hnor1.Init.NSBank = FSMC_NORSRAM_BANK1;
  hnor1.Init.DataAddressMux = FSMC_DATA_ADDRESS_MUX_ENABLE;
  hnor1.Init.MemoryType = FSMC_MEMORY_TYPE_NOR;
  hnor1.Init.MemoryDataWidth = FSMC_NORSRAM_MEM_BUS_WIDTH_8;
  hnor1.Init.BurstAccessMode = FSMC_BURST_ACCESS_MODE_ENABLE;
  hnor1.Init.WaitSignalPolarity = FSMC_WAIT_SIGNAL_POLARITY_LOW;
  hnor1.Init.WrapMode = FSMC_WRAP_MODE_DISABLE;
  hnor1.Init.WaitSignalActive = FSMC_WAIT_TIMING_BEFORE_WS;
  hnor1.Init.WriteOperation = FSMC_WRITE_OPERATION_DISABLE;
  hnor1.Init.WaitSignal = FSMC_WAIT_SIGNAL_DISABLE;
  hnor1.Init.ExtendedMode = FSMC_EXTENDED_MODE_DISABLE;
  hnor1.Init.AsynchronousWait = FSMC_ASYNCHRONOUS_WAIT_DISABLE;
  hnor1.Init.WriteBurst = FSMC_WRITE_BURST_DISABLE;
  hnor1.Init.PageSize = FSMC_PAGE_SIZE_NONE;
  /* Timing */
  Timing.AddressSetupTime = 15;
  Timing.AddressHoldTime = 15;
  Timing.DataSetupTime = 255;
  Timing.BusTurnAroundDuration = 15;
  Timing.CLKDivision = 16;
  Timing.DataLatency = 17;
  Timing.AccessMode = FSMC_ACCESS_MODE_A;
  /* ExtTiming */

  if (HAL_NOR_Init(&hnor1, &Timing, NULL) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }

}
```

Comment: We are not a debugging service. Use a debugger and step through your code. Also check **why and where ** the hardfault occurs. If unsure, read the documentation, it is freely available at ST and ARM.

Comment: On a sidenote: don't use that rubbish bloatware STlib/"HAL". It only complicates your code, slows it down and has no benefit at all. Write your driver directly to the hardware registers.

Comment: Look into the stack where you have the registers and position of the place where this HF occurred (easy to google), and debug this part of the code.